# GPU Instancing issue of a Custom shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Basically I followed this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html) to open gpu instancing for my custom vertex and fragment shaders. However, if I use `UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID, UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(name) / UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(name)` and so on in the shader but I don't use `#pragma multi_compile_instancing` at the beginning, then the Enable Instancing checkbox won't show and my problem is that is there any drawback if I do so?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it is required for functionality

"#pragma multi_compile_instancing" is what brings in the instancing code. Sort of like a "using" statement in c#.  If this is not included you will not have any GPU instancing.

Is there an issue with the checkbox?

If you don't want instancing don't include any of it. If you want instancing you must include it all.